# How to update ngnix configuration of ngnix ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have installed `ngnix` ingress controller on `K8 cluster` using helm chart.

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --namespace kube-system
```

I want to update below values in `ngnix.conf` file of `ngnix` ingress controller:

```
 1. proxy-connect-timeout
 2. proxy-read-timeout
 3. location 

{
    add_header "Cache-Control" "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    add_header "Pragma" "no-cache";
    add_header "Expires" "-1";
}
```

I have used below ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-iningress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
                  location / {
                     add_header "Cache-Control" "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
                     add_header "Pragma" "no-cache";
                     add_header "Expires" "-1";
                  }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ui
        backend:
          serviceName: sift-ui-service
          servicePort: {{ .Values.service.sift_ui.port }}
```

Then when I check ngnix.conf using

```
kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-b4477bdf7-gwt8v -n kube-system -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

`proxy-connect-timeout` and `proxy-read-timeout` do not get updated.  It shows default values, and server-snippet also not get added.

Can anyone tell me how to `update/add` configuration of `ngnix` ingress controller?

Comment: It is possible, that the annotations are incorrect. Look through the documentation on https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md for proper ones and compare them with defined. Additionally, possibly you use incorrect values, for example `"300s"` insted of `"300"`. Also, could you provide logs for `ingress-controller`, there should be errors or messages about applying  the annotations, command is `kubectl logs -n kube-system <ingress-controller-podname>`

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution to the above problem.
I had used

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300s"
```

instead of

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
```

and

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet
```

instead of

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet
```

Solution :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-iningress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header "Cache-Control" "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
      add_header "Pragma" "no-cache";
      add_header "Expires" "-1";
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ui
        backend:
          serviceName: sift-ui-service
          servicePort: {{ .Values.service.sift_ui.port }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having the problem?

Actually I faced the same issue on proxy-body-size configuration. The value does'nt take effect to the nginx-ingress-controller pod.

I did some researches and found the below solution:

```
(before) nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
(after) ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
```

What I did was omitting the "nginx" in the annotations setting.

I think you may try to configure the annotations as follow:

```
metadata:
  name: test-iningress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300s"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300s"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: "0"
```

Hope it works on your environment!